# openssl library for Windows for Generating a Development Key Hash for Facebook login for Android app

Tags: android, facebook, openssl, facebook-login, facebook-android-sdk

To ensure the authenticity of the interactions between my app and Facebook, I need to supply Facebook with the Android key hash for your development environment. I am trying to generate a Development Key Hash for my Android development environment. In the official Facebook documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/ for my account, I found the following information:

[image]

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Users\USERNAME\.android\debug.keystore" | "PATH_TO_OPENSSL_LIBRARY\bin\openssl" sha1 -binary | "PATH_TO_OPENSSL_LIBRARY\bin\openssl" base64
```

The problem for me is with "openssl-for-windows openssl library for Windows from the Google Code Archive" because that takes to a broken link:

https://code.google.com/archive/p/openssl-for-windows/downloads

Are there alternative sources or ways to install the "openssl library for Windows"? Thank you.

**UPDATE 1**:

I am using https://web.archive.org/web/20220623092750/https://code.google.com/archive/p/openssl-for-windows/downloads to access the broken link I mentioned.

Comment: So you're doing this on a Windows box ? I suppose just building OpenSSL is out of the question? that would certainly solve your problem. It's not really being used for anything magical here anyway besides hashing the cert and then bas64-encoding the hash to generate your token. if push came to shove you could always just copy the  keystore up to a Linux/Mac box where the JDK and OpenSSL are installed, and just run it from there. Building OpenSSL was made a LOT simpler with 3.0.x, so if you have a compliant toolchain that is certainly an option if you really want to stick to windows.

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes, I am doing this on a Windows box. I am even having issues with the generation of the `debug.keystore` file, as I mention at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73616137/keytool-exportcert-alias-androiddebugkey-keystore-c-debug-keystore.

Answer (score 1):

Download and install OpenSSL from https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html Win32 OpenSSL v#.#.# OR Win64 OpenSSL v#.#.# , make sure to get the non-light versions. Add the OpenSSL directory to your path.

Comment: Alternatively you can use 
```winget install -e --id ShiningLight.OpenSSL``` from commandline